# BudgetValue for SalesRegion not updated when Slicer selection changes

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a problem with my budget fact table. The budget is stored per ProductGroup (DimProduct) and SalesRegion(DimCustomer).

In the Dimension Usage of the cube I've set the regular relationship between the FactBudget and the two dimensions accordingly.

In Excel, let's say I know filter my DimCustomer with a Slicer for CustomerTyp. Is it now possible to get only the budget value from the SalesRegions from this subset of customers? Right now, the budget value does not change for different selections of the slicer.

Any help is appreciated.

Best regards, Sebastian